# Images not adjusting inside the grid

Tags: html, css, grid

I got 2 columns grid with following layout:

[image]

My issue is that when I use images inside the right column (1 image inside each box)..Images overflow and whole grid kind of acts weird.

It looks something like this:
[image]

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/kazmi066/pen/MWXGgaL?editors=1100

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 70vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
}

.col1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.col2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="box1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property"/></div>
    <div class="box2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the images to adjust inside the boxes perfectly without the need of custom height and width so that any size of image can work in this scenario.

Comment: use padding on Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

- I used `grid-auto-rows` to create 2 rows with specific height.
- Then added span to adjust the column accordingly to cover both rows.

```js
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  gap: 14px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 280px 280px;
}

.col1 {
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/8;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: red;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column: 8/13;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.col2 img:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-auto-rows: 220px 120px;
  }
  
  .col1 {
    grid-column: 1/13;
  }

  .col2 {
    grid-column: 1/13;
    grid-row: span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564013799919-ab600027ffc6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YmVhdXRpZnVsJTIwaG91c2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property"/>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/186077/pexels-photo-186077.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-binyamin-mellish-186077.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="property" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Final output now:
[image]

> Solution-2: Found Another better solution with `Grid-template-areas` I guess which looks more cleaner:

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  gap: 14px;
  grid-template-areas: 
            "mainImage mainImage otherImage1"
            "mainImage mainImage otherImage1"
            "mainImage mainImage otherImage2"
            "mainImage mainImage otherImage2"
}
.mainImage {
  grid-area: mainImage;
}
.otherImage1 {
  grid-area: otherImage1;
}
.otherImage2 {
  grid-area: otherImage2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"> 
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property" class="mainImage" /> 
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564013799919-ab600027ffc6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YmVhdXRpZnVsJTIwaG91c2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property" class="otherImage1" /> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/186077/pexels-photo-186077.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-binyamin-mellish-186077.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="property" class="otherImage2" /> 
</div>
<h1>something else here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

fit would be object-fit: contain; for the image not cover.

but if the ratio of the image is not the ratio of the box, you'll have blank

you can put the image in background of box1, box2... with a background size cover. It will cover entirely and clipped the overflow. If box ratio "totally" different of the image, lot of image can be clipped, but it's not so often.

Comment: Yep `contain` won't work as it leaves blank spaces. Also I cannot use `background-Image` because I am dealing with API dynamic data so won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way, only CSS, nothing is changed in your HTML

2 points:

1- it's using clip-path
2- image fill box space, but are clipped otherwise blank space

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 70vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.col1 {
  background: red;
}

.col2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 34vh 34vh;
  background: orange;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="box1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property" /></div>
    <div class="box2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8N3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="property" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

based on your grid max-height in vh, I defined all others same kind of values in vh. Lot more consistent and avoid some little strange pixels or lines here or there depending of window size.

I put a nested grid inside col2 where box1 box2 go. box have a clip-path with inset 0, meaning clipping everything out.

Comment: Don't know why you are making it more complicated by adding `grid` inside column and using `clip-path`....Also this logic fails if I change height of parent `Grid`.
I have found one solution which I might post here in some hours maybe Thanks